# SQL exception for comparing operation in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have these 2 tables joined up and i made a statement that period has to be > 2013.10.01. But i want this statement ineffective for fields where code='A722' and host_country='Poland'. I tried using case statement in where clause, but it doesn't seem to be working and i can't seem to figure out why. Any alternatives for this?

```
with table1 (person_id, period) as (
   select 12, date '2013-08-01' from dual union all
   select 13, date '2015-03-16' from dual union all
   select 14, date '2015-04-22' from dual union all
   select 15, date '2015-06-13' from dual
 ),
 table2 (person_id, code, host_country) as (
   select 12, 'A8722', 'poland' from dual union all
   select 13, 'B8422', 'china' from dual union all
   select 14, 'Z8725', 'sweden' from dual union all
   select 15, 'G8726' ,'Germany' from dual
 ) 

 select 
 t1.person_id, 
 t2.code, 
 t2.host_country,
 t1.period 
 from table1 t1, table2 t2 
 where t1.person_id=t2.person_id
 AND t1.period> CASE WHEN t2.code NOT IN ('A8722') AND t2.host_country NOT IN('poland') THEN to_date('2013.10.01','YYYY.MM.DD') END
```

Link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/4813/0).

Comment: Skip the THEN stuff, just do AND.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you show output of to_date() function? I believe there are date-format mismatches as rest of query seems fine.

Comment: What is SQL Exception? Add exception text here too. There is no SQL Exception in your provided SQLFiddle link for above query.

Comment: Exception is that i don't want t1.period>to_date('2013.10.01','YYYY.MM.DD') where host_country='Poland' and code='A8722'

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following query.

```
with table1 (person_id, period) as (
   select 12, date '2013-08-01' from dual union all
   select 13, date '2015-03-16' from dual union all
   select 14, date '2015-04-22' from dual union all
   select 15, date '2015-06-13' from dual
 ),
 table2 (person_id, code, host_country) as (
   select 12, 'A8722', 'poland' from dual union all
   select 13, 'B8422', 'china' from dual union all
   select 14, 'Z8725', 'sweden' from dual union all
   select 15, 'G8726' ,'Germany' from dual
 ) 

 select 
 t1.person_id, 
 t2.code, 
 t2.host_country,
 t1.period 
 from table1 t1, table2 t2 
 where t1.person_id=t2.person_id
 AND ((t2.code  IN ('A8722') AND t2.host_country  IN ('poland')) OR  t1.period>  to_date('2013.10.01','YYYY.MM.DD'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your statement to be

```
  and t1.period > CASE
                     WHEN t2.code NOT IN ('A8722') AND t2.host_country NOT IN('poland') THEN
                       date '2013-10-01'
                     ELSE 
                       date '0001-01-01'
                   END
```

For Poland it would always pass

If your dates could be B.C. (which would be funny) you can use the lowest date in Oracle (check docs).